# ExtJS: Layout run failed with gridpanel and default layout (fit)

Tags: extjs

I have a gridpanel which is failing the layout run with ext-dev and the context diagnostics on.

I tried with the page analyzer and got this:

```
    gridview-1068<tableview>
    headercontainer-1066.columnWidthsDone (=undefined)
    dirty: false
    setBy: ??
```

I am in the process of **upgrading from 4.1 to 4.2**. Other than CSS changes, the only problem is this grid.

It is bound to a store, the store has records, but the gridview is empty and has no nodes. So i am assuming this layout issue is related.

Changing layout to `auto` on the gridpanel fixes it but results in a still empty grid.

Any idea what this could be?

**Edit:**

I fixed the grid not displaying at all by a bad method call deep in the code base. But still I get the layout error, although it doesn't seem to affect much. Maybe because i have `header: false` so the failed `headercontainer` makes no difference.

Comment: try setting [shrinkWrapDock](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.AbstractPanel-cfg-shrinkWrapDock) to `true`

Comment: @sra i tried that and i get the same layout error when using dev/pageanalyzer :/ i have header to false too FYI.

Comment: Post the code of grid configuration and creation. Also, where do you use 'fit' layout?